# Python request authentication without password

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, python-requests

I have a need to log in to an administrative profile on a site using 81 port. Username is "admin", and a password is empty. That is, if I open the login window through the browser, I will only need to specify the username in the input form.

I'm trying to do this:
`s = requests.session`

But using `s.get(url=f'http://{ip}:81', auth=('admin', ''))` i get (Responce [401])

And also using `s.get(url=f'http://{ip}:81', auth=('admin', None))` i get (Responce [401])

Question: How can I get  (Responce [200]) without password with python request?

Comment: You could use `tcpdump` or a logging proxy to compare the request made by the browser with the request made by `requests` and see how they differ.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved:

```
s.get(f'http://ip', timeout = 10, verify = False, auth = HTTPDigestAuth('admin', ''))
```